# Duplicate css lines using html5reset

Tags: css, html, reset

I'm using html5reset from http://html5reset.org for the first time. The issue I'm seeing is that the file core.css is being loaded twice or something. If you pull up firebug, you can see that for every element you click on there is a core.css and a core.css #2.

I can't figure out what is causing it to load twice. My site is http://ratemymechanic.us

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have found this in your HTML markup:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ratemymechanic.us/assets/css/main.css" /> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ratemymechanic.us/assets/css/core.css" />
```

in `main.css`, you're importing `core.css` too, hence you're applying it twice:

```
@import url("core.css");
```

Comment: I guess I've never even looked in main.css. I wonder if html5reset knows that they have an import plus a stylesheet declaration in their template. Thanks for pointing that out to me.